# How to pass list view data to another activity

Tags: java, android, json

I have successfully get json data and made a list view. Now i want to send some extras but before send extras i tried to show a tost for testing. But the tost always return me the last id mentioned as name. :(

(I'm new in android dev)

Here is my work. What wrong i did?
Tost showing the position perfectly but the it shows the last name filed as a constant. Like if i click on first filed it shows me LAST field, If i click on the middle filed it also shows me the last filed.

```
private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private ListView lv;
private ListView listView;


ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> channelList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.live_stream);

    channelList = new ArrayList<>();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(mMessageClickedHandler);

    new GetChannel().execute();
}





private class GetChannel extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Toast.makeText(LiveStreaming.this, "Streaming list is loading", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String url = "http://ubpower.net/cricktv/tv.json";
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
        if (jsonStr != null) {

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray channel = jsonObj.getJSONArray("channel");

                for (int i = 0; i < channel.length(); i++) {
                   JSONObject c = channel.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = c.getString("id");
                    name = c.getString("name");
                    String quality = c.getString("quality");
                    address = c.getString("address");


                    // tmp hash map for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> channel_hash = new HashMap<>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    channel_hash.put("id", id);
                    channel_hash.put("name", name);
                    channel_hash.put("quality", quality);
                    channel_hash.put("address", address);



                    // adding contact to contact list
                    channelList.add(channel_hash);
                }



            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

            }

        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(LiveStreaming.this, channelList,
                R.layout.stream_list, new String[]{ "name","quality","address"},
                new int[]{R.id.channel_title, R.id.channel_quality, R.id.channel_address});
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);



    }






}
```

//******************** Adapter for click on list item and pass datat

```
public AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mMessageClickedHandler = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {

        Toast.makeText(LiveStreaming.this, "click item" + position + name , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(LiveStreaming.this, video_view.class);;
      // intent.putExtra("address", address);
        startActivity(intent);


    }

};
```

}

Comment: `But I'm unable to click on the list item and can't send extras to another activity. here is my adapter.` what have you tried? I can't see your attempts in your code.

Comment: Wher's the onItemClickListener ?

Comment: added. I have edit and add all my work. Can you help? Please

Answer (score 0):

To get taps, you need to add an item click listener to the adapter. Here is one way of doing that:

```
private OnItemClickListener mMessageClickedHandler = new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Do something in response to the click
    }
};

listView.setOnItemClickListener(mMessageClickedHandler);
```

To get the data into a new activity, the simplest is to add those data fields to the Intent used to create the new activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);

intent.putExtra("SomeKey", value );

startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Awesome it solved.

But Tost showing the position perfectly but it shows the last name filed as a constant. Like if i click on first filed it shows me LAST field, If i click on the middle filed it also shows me the last filed. why? :(

Comment: I'm glad that suggestion solved it. :)    As to your second question, I don't understand what you mean. Use the position or the id to lookup the right data. putExtra's first parameter is the name of the argument, the second is the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
//This may help
//Attach and Send date to another activity:

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("Name",Object); //This is for a String
i.setClass(CurrentClass.this, Class.class);
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);

//Receive Data on second Activity:

Bundle bundle = null;
bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String myString = bundle.getString("Name");//this is for String
```

Comment: Solved. Thanks. But

Tost showing the position perfectly but the it shows the last name filed as a constant. Like if i click on first filed it shows me LAST field, If i click on the middle filed it also shows me the last filed.